# Install npm package programmatically after npm decision to drop programmatic API

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Before npm 8.0 was possible to install npm packages programmatically, like this:

```
const npm = require('npm');
npm.load((error) => {
    if (error) return console.log(error);
    npm.commands.install([package], (error, data) => {
        if (error) return console.log(error);
        // command succeeded, and data might have some info
    });
    npm.on('log', (message) => {
        console.log(message);
    });
});
```

But they decided to refactor things and the support for programmatic API was dropped. Of course, there is the option to keep npm version bellow `7.24.2` which is the last supporting version, but some vulnerabilities were found in those versions and despite the fact that they are harmless in my case the console looks scarry for users.

Is there any reliable alternative to this issue?

Comment: executed above code and got the message: Error: The programmatic API was removed in npm v8.0.0

Comment: @AlexeyObukhov yes, this is exactly what I said! :)

Comment: yes, now it is impossible to use this code. other options: command line or [other libraries](https://github.com/Manak/npm-programmatic)

Comment: @AlexeyObukhov I saw that library, thank you, it looks obsolete, last updated 3 years ago, and just for bumping dependencies. Created 5 years ago. I think it should be something more reliable somewhere since the npm support drop, because there are lots of libraries depending on this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by using `child_process`.:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

const run = async (cmd) => {
    const child = exec(cmd, (err) => {
        if (err) console.error(err);
    });
    child.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
    child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
    await new Promise((resolve) => child.on('close', resolve));
};

module.exports = run;
```

then... in another file in some function we can call:

```
await run(`npm install ${package}`);
```